# Showing that the mean of the dependent variable is independent of the explanatory variable.

Tags: statistics

I've currently got a stat problem that I can't immediatly interpret. I have a dataset that I have done a linear regression test on, and I have now been asked to determine if the mean of the dependent variable is independent of the explanatory variable. I'm assuming this means doing a test to check if beta = 0, that is, a change in the explanatory variable does not result in any change in the dependent variable. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the slope is not significantly different from zero, then one would conclude that there is no linear relationship between the two variables.

Comment: Good, that's what I assumed. Thanks!